# labeling feature based on defined Value Map in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, domains, labeling

I have some defined Value Maps as .csv and I want to label features according to this definitions. But when I use simple label expression, labels are "raw values" instead of "description values" - ignore defined Value Maps.

Is there some way to label features correctly?

As a best option, I need to build an expression with several attributes to label like this:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem (QGIS 2.18.16).

A working example with a point layer "test" and a CSV-file label.csv.

Alternatively you can use a **JOIN**:

[image]

[image]

Or a **Virtual Layer**:

[image]

**UPDATE 1**

If you have joined a csv to your layer with 3 attributes you can label this way (like the example in the question).

```
attribute_1 = 'HP
attribute_2 = 41
attribute_3 = 'h'
```

label expression:

`"attribute_1" || '\n' || "attribute_2" || ' - ' || "attribute_3"`

With `\n` as a line break.

Additionally you can change the line height in `Labels > Formatting`. Also use Center as Alignment to center both lines.

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

When you have NULL values you can `coalesce` for every attribute:

```
coalesce( "attribute_1", '') || '\n' || coalesce( "attribute_2", '') || ' - ' || coalesce( "attribute_3", '')
```

Result:

[image]

**UPDATE 3**

Here is another way to label the features without using `coalesce` and to get rid of the hyphens when `attribute_2` or `attribute_3` is NULL.

```
CASE 
    WHEN  "attribute_1" IS NULL THEN  "attribute_2"  || ' - ' ||  "attribute_3" 
    WHEN  "attribute_1" IS NULL AND  "attribute_2" IS NULL THEN  "attribute_3" 
    WHEN  "attribute_1" IS NULL AND  "attribute_3" IS NULL THEN  "attribute_2" 
    WHEN  "attribute_2" IS NULL THEN  "attribute_1" || '\n' || "attribute_3"    
    WHEN  "attribute_2" IS NULL AND  "attribute_3" IS NULL THEN  "attribute_1" 
    WHEN  "attribute_3" IS NULL THEN  "attribute_1" || '\n' || "attribute_2" 
    ELSE "attribute_1" || '\n' || "attribute_2" || ' - ' ||  "attribute_3" 
END
```

Comment: Thank you. I edited my question. Filnally I will need several attributes (3 - 4) defined by Value Map to build an expression. Is it possible to do this in Join or Virtual layer?

Comment: You can join multiple attributes to your point vector layer and select multiple columns in the virtual layer selection.

Comment: Thats exactly what I want! Thank you! Works well! After all, one  additional question. What if I build an expression for 3 attributes, like you, but some polygones have only two, third is Null. Its possilbe to include this to expression to label only with two attributes?

Comment: I've updated my answer regarding to the NULL values.

Comment: Huh. I thought the represent_value() function was supposed to do what OP had asked for, but I can't get it to work in QGIS 3.0.1. It just puts brackets around the value... it must be some kind of bug?